# Как открыть спойлер при нажатии на ссылку?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать что бы при нажитии по ссылке якорь, открывался спойлер с установленным айди?

```js
   $(document).on('click','.spb-trigger',function(e){e.preventDefault();$(this).toggleClass('active');
 $(this).parent().find('.spb-block').first().slideToggle(1000);})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <a href="#link">
   Сыылка на якорь
 </a> 

<br>
<br>
  <a class="spb-trigger" id="link" href="#">
   Открыть
 </a> 
  <div class="spb-block"  style="display: none;">
1
    
 </div>
```

Comment: у вас две ссылки, на что нажимая что должно произойти?

Comment: А на кой вам jQuery??? Это же можно сделать на голом css

Comment: @Arsen что при нажатии на ссылку "Сыылка на якорь " открывался спойлер тот что ниже "Открыть" и там выпадет "1"

Comment: @Ljil ну так уже пошел, оптимизировать нету времени, много где этот  спойле уже работает, плюс jQuery все равно работает для других скриптов.

Comment: Тоесть что бы когда нажал чел. на якорь страничка опустилась и сработал спойлер тоесть открылся. Что бы при опускании после нажатии не пришлось еще нажимать на спойлер что бы увидеть нужную инфу! Вот так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.spb-trigger', function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $(this).toggleClass('active');
 $(this).parent().find('.spb-block').first().slideToggle(1000);
})


$('.main').on('click', function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var items = $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top;
 var body = $("html, body");
 body.stop().animate({
  scrollTop: items + 'px'
 }, '1000', 'swing', function () {
  $('.spb-block').slideDown();
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <a class="main" href="#link">
   Сыылка на якорь
 </a> 

<br>
<br>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
  <a class="spb-trigger" id="link" href="#">
   Открыть
 </a> 
  <div class="spb-block"  style="display: none;">
1
    
 </div> 
 
 <br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если переместить класс spb-trigger из ссылки "Открыть" в ссылку "Сыылка на якорь", то код сработает.

```
<a class="spb-trigger" href="#link">Сыылка на якорь</a><br><br>
<a id="link" href="#">Открыть</a>
<div class="spb-block" style="display: none;">1</div>
```

Comment: Я знаю это) А есть другой путь?

Comment: Зачем другой путь?

Comment: Ваш js обрабатывает клик по элементу с классом spb-trigger. http://joxi.net/v29W73LIZZzeQr Устанавливайте другой класс у ссылки и меняйте класс в коде js, если нельзя убирать класс у ссылки открыть.